# Como inserir uma LI em uma UL com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, css

estou querendo adicionar uma LI entre duas LI de uma UL. Eu não tenho acesso ao codigo CSS/HTML do template do site, se não criaria facilmente, então to pensando em adicionar via html e javascript.

Já tentei de tudo e não consegui, alguem teria uma ideia de como poderia realizar isso?

queria inserir essa LI

```html
<li>
    <a href="https://www.xyz.com.br/" title="XYZ">
        <img src="https://xyz.com.br/xyz.png" alt="xyz" width="200px">
    </a>
</li>
```

Segue o codigo...

```html
<div class="atalhos-mobile visible-phone fundo-secundario borda-principal" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 128); border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(44, 43, 43, 0.18);">

<ul>

    <li class="menu-mobile-botao">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="slide-collapse" data-target="#slide-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <svg class="icone-menu" style="fill: rgb(255, 213, 65);">
                <use xlink:href="#icone-menu"></use>
            </svg>
        </button>
    </li>

    **//////////// QUERIA COLOCAR A LI AQUI ////////////////////////////**

    <li class="home-mobile">
        <a href="https://www.xyz.com.br/" class="">
            <svg class="icone-home" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                <use xlink:href="#icone-home"></use>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1º Colocar um id na ul
`<ul id="lista">`

2º Utiliza a função abaixo em algum evento exemplo

```
<button onclick="adicionar()">Adicionar linha</button>

function adicionarLi() {
  var lista  = document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML;
  lista = lista +"<li>"+seuTextoAqui+"</li>";
  document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML = lista;
}
```

Comment: não seria possível resolver o problema apenas usando:
`document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML += "<li>"+seuTextoAqui+"</li>"` dentro da função adicionarLi?

Comment: Também não seria mais interessante usar `querySelector`?

Comment: Eu não tenho acesso ao tema/template para dar ID a UL. Se não faria facilmente. Este que está sendo o gargalo. mas obrigado por tentar ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Vou tentar ajudar utilizando tal exemplo

```
<h2>frutas</h2>

<input type="text" id="frutas" />

<button onclick="adicionar()">Adicionar frutas</button>

<br>

<ul id="lista">
  <li>banana</li>
  <li>morango</li>
  <li>manga</li>
  <li>uva</li>
</ul>
```

Agora, o *JavaScript* para a função *adicionar*

```
function adicionar() {
  var fru = document.getElementById("frutas").value;
  var lista  = document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML;
  lista = lista +"<li>"+fru+"</li>";

  document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML = lista;
}
```

Comment: obrigado amigo, eu entendi. mas na verdade eu queria que o elemento estivesse entre 2 LI. No onload da pagina. Fosse um elemento do site. Eu ate fiz um novo post pra exemplicficar melhor https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/414641/como-adicionar-um-li-em-uma-ul-atrav%C3%A9s-de-javascript